# Extension Methods for IEnumerable<Enum>?

Tags: c#, enums, extension-methods, ienumerable

I have a bunch of different enums, such as...

```
 public enum MyEnum
{
  [Description("Army of One")]
  one, 
  [Description("Dynamic Duo")]
  two,
  [Description("Three Amigo's")]
  three,
  [Description("Fantastic Four")]
  four,
  [Description("The Jackson Five")]
  five
}
```

I wrote an extension method for any Enum to get the Description attribute if it has one.  Simple enough right...

```
public static string GetDescription(this Enum currentEnum)
{
  var fi = currentEnum.GetType().GetField(currentEnum.ToString());
  var da = (DescriptionAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(fi, typeof(DescriptionAttribute));
  return da != null ? da.Description : currentEnum.ToString();
}
```

I can use this very simply and it works like a charm, returning the description or ToString() as expected.

Here is the problem though.  I would like to have the ability to call this on an IEnumerable of MyEnum, YourEnum, or SomeoneElsesEnum.  So I wrote the following extension just as simply.

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetDescriptions(this IEnumerable<Enum> enumCollection)
{
  return enumCollection.ToList().ConvertAll(a => a.GetDescription());
}
```

This doesn't work.  It compiles fine as a method, but using it gives the following error:

```
Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<MyEnum>' to System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Enum>'
```

So why is this?
Can I make this work?

The only answer I have found at this point is to write extension methods for generic T as follows:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetDescriptions<T>(this List<T> myEnumList) where T : struct, IConvertible
public static string GetDescription<T>(this T currentEnum) where T : struct, IConvertible
```

Someone must have a better answer for this, or an explanation of why I can extend an Enum but not an IEnumerable of Enum...
Anyone?

Comment: Since C# 7.3 (from 2018), you can write the generic constraint as `where T : struct, System.Enum` which at least ensures the method is used only with real enum types.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

.NET generic covariance only works for reference types. Here, `MyEnum` is a value type, and `System.Enum` is a reference type (casting from an enum type to `System.Enum` is a boxing operation).

So, an `IEnumerable<MyEnum>` is not an `IEnumerable<Enum>`, as that would change the representation of each enumerated item from a value type to a reference type; only representation-preserving conversions are allowed. You need to use the generic method trick you've posted to get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from v4 C# supports co-variance and contra-variance for generic interfaces and delegates. But unfortunately, these *-variances work only for reference types, it doesn't work for value types, such as enums.