# Extension for IEnumerable<Enum>

Tags: c#, enums, extension-methods

I have the following:

```
var a = RoleEnum.Member;
var b = new List<RoleEnum> { RoleEnum.Member, RoleEnum.Editor };

string c = a.Humanize();
string d = b.Humanize();
```

While humanize is recognized in a.Humanize it is not recognized in b.Humanize.

The humanize extensions are as follows:

```
public static String Humanize(this Enum source) {
  return source.Attribute<DescriptionAttribute>().Description;      
}

public static String Humanize<T>(this IEnumerable<Enum> source) {
  return String.Join(", ", source.Cast<T>().Select(x => x.Attribute<DescriptionAttribute>().Description));
}
```

What am I missing here?

**UPDATE 1**

I changed the second extension to:

```
public static String Humanize<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source) where T : struct, IConvertible {
  return String.Join(", ", source.Cast<T>().Select(x => x.Attribute<DescriptionAttribute>().Description));
} // Humanize
```

But now I am having problems with the Attribute extension which is:

```
public static T Attribute<T>(this Enum value) where T : Attribute {
  MemberInfo info = value.GetType().GetMember(value.ToString()).FirstOrDefault();
  if (info != null)
    return (T)info.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(T), false).FirstOrDefault();
  return null;
} // Attribute
```

Could someone help me in solving this?

Comment: see:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5162389/extension-methods-for-ienumerableenum

Comment: I just updated my question to consider what is present on the other post. But I am still having problems ... Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: `x.Attribute<...>` where `x` is only known to be a value type that implements `IConvertible` cannot hope to find extension methods for `Enum`. Maybe change that extension method the same way? That is, define it for all value types that implement `IConvertible`.

Comment: @hvd That was my idea but I wasn't able to do it ... Maybe I am missing something. Could you suggest a solution?

Comment: @MDMoura I was talking about basically `public static T Attribute<TEnum, T>(this TEnum value) where TEnum : struct, IConvertible where T : Attribute { ... }`, but I now realise that this would prevent your `x.Attribute<DescriptionAttribute>()` syntax from working: it would have to be changed to `x.Attribute<T, DescriptionAttribute>()`. That's not desirable. I see that tchrikch has already posted a similar approach as an answer that avoids that problem.

Answer (score 0):

One possible kick-it-in-the-teeth solution is to force it back to an `object` before casting to an `Enum`:

```
public static String Humanize<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source) where T : struct, IConvertible 
{
  return String.Join(", ", source.Cast<T>().Select(x => ((Enum)((object)x)).Attribute<DescriptionAttribute>().Description));
}
```

This worked for me and printed the description for each Enum item in the list. I honestly hope somebody has a better solution though, because this has a pretty strong code smell!

Answer (score 0):

Use `IConvertible` interface as type of argument for `Attribute<T>()` extension. Full code below

```
   public static class EnumExtensions
{
    public static String Humanize(this Enum source)
    {
        return source.Attribute<DescriptionAttribute>().Description;
    }

    public static String Humanize<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source) where T : struct, IConvertible
    {
        return String.Join(", ", source.Cast<T>().Select(x => x.Attribute<DescriptionAttribute>().Description));
    } // Humanize


    public static T Attribute<T>(this IConvertible value) where T : Attribute
    {
        MemberInfo info = value.GetType().GetMember(value.ToString()).FirstOrDefault();
        if (info != null)
            return (T)info.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(T), false).FirstOrDefault();
        return null;
    } // Attribute
}
```